# How to read the xml file in wordpress?

Tags: feed, xml

I have a feed link http://www.wdcdn.net/rss/presentation/library/client/iowa/id/128b053b916ea1f7f20233e8a26bc45d and I have to read all the elements of feed including credits, here is how the feed is displayed

```
<item>
  <title>
    <![CDATA[Dave&#39;s Lawnmower Bish Bash]]>
  </title>
  <link>http://cache.wdcdn.net/cdn/asset/view/client/filmconstruction/package/library/id/918787/format/o/h/503e4d2418da8c167f7a75d25638a35e/?7a6013aef28682d61703dff120d21b12266b54a2a637283d7d4f0a0843a6f755b7d8fa6f17d0ac1585d9530a052e29240a1a3c75fb</link>
  <guid>http://filmconstruction.wdcdn.net/l/p/?presentation=a211defdbe060c7e8f42e884b7e8f584#918787</guid>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[DW_MLA_Lamb_DavesLawnMowerBishBash_30.mov]]>
  </description>
  <pubDate>Mon, 30 Apr 2012 21:49:55 -0700</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="http://cache.wdcdn.net/cdn/asset/view/client/filmconstruction/package/library/id/918787/format/o/h/503e4d2418da8c167f7a75d25638a35e/DW_MLA_Lamb_DavesLawnMowerBishBash_30.mov?7a6013aef28682d61703dff120d21b12266b54a2a637283d7d4f0a0843a6f755b7d8fa6f17d0ac1585d9530a052e29240a1a3c75fb.mov" type="video/quicktime" length="6289971"/>
  <media:content url="http://cache.wdcdn.net/cdn/asset/view/client/filmconstruction/package/library/id/918787/format/o/h/503e4d2418da8c167f7a75d25638a35e/DW_MLA_Lamb_DavesLawnMowerBishBash_30.mov?7a6013aef28682d61703dff120d21b12266b54a2a637283d7d4f0a0843a6f755b7d8fa6f17d0ac1585d9530a052e29240a1a3c75fb.mov" fileSize="6289971" type="video/quicktime" duration="0" height="360" width="640"/>
  <media:thumbnail url="http://cache.wdcdn.net/cdn/asset/view/client/filmconstruction/package/library/id/918787/format/t/size/lg/h/87884cce4f657e643d3df42ccc623101/library_918787_lg.jpg?7a6013aef28682d61703dff120d21b12266b54a2a637283d7d4f0a0843a6f755b7d8fa6f17d0ac1585d9530a052e29240a1a3c75fb.jpg" height="360" width="640"/>
  <media:thumbnail url="http://cache.wdcdn.net/cdn/asset/view/client/filmconstruction/package/library/id/918787/format/t/size/sm/h/87884cce4f657e643d3df42ccc623101/library_918787_sm.jpg?7a6013aef28682d61703dff120d21b12266b54a2a637283d7d4f0a0843a6f755b7d8fa6f17d0ac1585d9530a052e29240a1a3c75fb.jpg" height="101" width="180"/>
  <media:credit role="client" scheme="urn:feeds-wiredrive-com:credits">
    <![CDATA[MLA]]>
  </media:credit>
  <media:credit role="agency" scheme="urn:feeds-wiredrive-com:credits">
    <![CDATA[BMF]]>
  </media:credit>
  <media:credit role="director" scheme="urn:feeds-wiredrive-com:credits">
    <![CDATA[David Wood]]>
  </media:credit>
  <media:keywords>
    <![CDATA[Humour]]>
  </media:keywords>
</item>
```

I have used this code to read the content but can not get the all the credits with this code

```
$file   = file_get_contents('http://www.wdcdn.net/rss/presentation/library/client/iowa/id/128b053b916ea1f7f20233e8a26bc45d'); 
$xml    =  simplexml_load_string($file);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://www.wdcdn.net/rss/presentation/library/client/iowa/id/128b053b916ea1f7f20233e8a26bc45d');
$arrFeeds = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $itemRSS = array ( 

                'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,                

                'guid' => $node->getElementsByTagName('guid')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'content' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'content')->item(0)->getAttribute('url'),
    'vwidth' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'content')->item(0)->getAttribute('width'),
    'vheight' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'content')->item(0)->getAttribute('height'),
    'thumbnail' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url'),
    'credit' => $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'credit')->item(0)->getAttribute('role') 
                );
        array_push($arrFeeds, $itemRSS);
}
```

How do I read all the credits of each item? Can anyone help me is finding solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is more a php question than a wordpress one.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. The OP is asking how to do it in WP. From his code you can see its not the correct way in WP. Someone could answer this by giving examples using the correct WP way of reading an XML feed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WordPress bundles and wraps SimplePie class for feed download, caching and processing. Retrieving namespaced data with it would be something like this:

```
$feed  = fetch_feed( 'http://www.wdcdn.net/rss/presentation/library/client/iowa/id/128b053b916ea1f7f20233e8a26bc45d' );
$items = $feed->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {

    $credit = $item->get_item_tags( 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'credit' );
    var_dump( $credit );
}
```

See [`fetch_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) in Codex.

Answer (score 0):

anyway, if you do something like this:

```
$medias = $node->getElementsByTagName('media');
foreach ( $medias as $media ) {
    $media_items[] = $media->nodeValue;
}
$itemRSS = array (
    'medias' => $media_items,
    // all the stuff you did
);
```

you should get your results.